# Gensim framework: Saving and storing word2vec keyed vectors

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I'am using the word2vec model and I have a problem with storing and reading it.

```
import gensim.models.keyedvectors as w2v
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

word_vectors = w2v.wv
word_vectors.save(filepath + "Vectors.bin")

m = word2vec.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(filepath + "Vectors.bin", binary=True)
```

I get following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

In the following way the laoding will work:

```
vectors = KeyedVectors.load(filepath + "Vectors.bin", mmap='r')
```

But If I then call

```
vectors.similar_by_word("cat")
```

I get following error: 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'

What am I doing wrong?
How can I use the save_word2vec_format() function?

Answer (score 2):

Your initial block of code that does `import gensim.models.keyedvectors as w2v` and `word_vectors = w2v.wv` doesn't make much sense.

Read literally, that is assigning the full Python code module `gensim.models.keyedvectors` to the variable `w2v`. That module isn't going to have a `.wv` property, so I wouldn't expect `word_vectors = w2v.wv` to even execute. It certainly wouldn't result in `word_vectors` then being an actual set of trained-up word-vectors, unless there's a bunch of other training code you're not showing.

Are you sure the code in your question is representative of what you're actually doing?

Nevertheless, if you did succeed in getting `word_vectors` to hold one of `gensim`'s `KeyedVectors` objects, filled with word-vectors you want to save, you then have two choices:

- To save the word-vectors in the same format as was used by Google's original `word2vec.c` release, you can use the `.save_word2vec_format(path, ...)` method. Then, to later reload those vectors, you'd use the matched `reloaded_vectors = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(path, ...)` method.
- To save the word-vectors in `gensim`'s own Python-based format, you can use the `.save(path)` method. Then, to later reload those vectors, you'd use the matched `reloaded_vectors = KeyedVectors.load(path)` method. This approach may save a little more info (if it's present from your training), such as word-counts. For efficiency with larger objects, it may store the bulk of the vectors into a separate file, which should be kept alongside the main `path` file if you move the files elsewhere, and allows the option (but not the requirement) of using `mmap` options later.

You can't mix and match these formats: a file saved by `save_word2vec_format()` can only be read by `load_word2vec_format()`, and a file saved by `save()` can only be read by `load()`.

Regarding your other `TypeError`, there's not enough info to speculate what's gone wrong. You'd need to edit your answer to add more details, and make the demonstrating code self-consistent.

For example, you show loading into a variable named `vectors`, but then an operation on a variable called `model`. This discrepancy hints the problem might be some other mismatch in your un-shown code.

Similarly, if you encounter any error, you should quote exactly the error message **and full error stack reported** into your question, so answerers can see exactly which lines of code, in your code and the libaries you are relying on, are involved in exactly your error. (This usually helps finger exactly the place where your expectations/code deviate from the library's requirements.)